# Rails submitting a form through ajax and updating the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I want to update a form submit through ajax without reloading the page and update the view according to it. I tried the different methods and failed as i m new to rails.

Here's the situation.

In modal

```
def new
    @new_entry = current_user.notes.build
    @words = current_user.notes
    @notes_false_list = current_user.notes.where(known: false).order("title").group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
    @notes_true_list = current_user.notes.where(known: true).order("title").group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
  end
```

In view the form code.

```
<%= form_for @new_entry, :html => {:class => 'home-form without-entry clearfix'}  do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Squirrel', autofocus: true, class: 'title-field pull-left' %>
      <%= f.submit '', class: 'btn home-add without-entry' %>
  <% end %>
```

The create action

```
def create
    @new_note = current_user.notes.build(new_note_params)
    if @new_note.save
      @notes_list = current_user.notes.count
      unless @new_note.user.any_entry
        @new_note.user.toggle!(:any_entry) if @notes_list >= 50
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

and finally in the view i want to change

```
<p class="instructions count-instruction text-center">
      <%= @words.count %>
    </p>
```

Spent a lot of time updating this with AJAX but failed everytime. Any there to help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try please post it here?

Comment: Hey @Deep Well i am having a form which simply grabs title from the user and updates its on DB and shows no of title count below. I dont want to reload page on form submission. So i want to do it in AJAX.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your code is good,but for **ajax**,

1. you need to add `remote=true` to your form.

   `<%= form_for(@image,:html=>{:id=>"your_form_id",:multipart => true,:remote=>true}) do |f |%>`
2. Moreover at your server side,**you need to create a js.erb** file in
   `views/users/show_updated_view.js.erb` to reply back to browser as its a js
   call and NOT html call and hence need to show the user that something happened(success/error) after form submission (if its `users_controller`),

so inside your action,you need something like:-

```
        respond_to do |format|  
            format.js { render 'users/show_updated_view'}
        end
```

3. And in `show_updated_view.js.erb`,you should update your view for the users to
   know that the view has been updated or form has been successfully
   submitted by either hiding the entire form/resetting the form or
   replacing the form with new div saying that data is updated..or anything that is intuitive.There are many ways though :).

   //here i am replacing your entire form with div having a message

   `$("#your_form_id").html("<div><p>You have submitted the form successfully.</p></div>")`;

**The name of the view can be anything but you need to take care of both success and failure.**

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [short article on doing AJAX with Rails](http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/). A few things to note:

1. Add `remote: true` in your `form_for`.
2. Include **format.js** in your controller so that it will render **create.js.erb**.
3. In **create.js.erb**, do something like this (not tested):

   `$("p.instructions").innerHTML("<%= @notes_list %>")`

Comment: Hey Yen-Ju This is the whole view page                                                     `<%= form_for @new_entry, :html => {:class => 'home-form without-entry clearfix'}, remote: true   do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Squirrel', autofocus: true, class: 'title-field pull-left' %>
      <%= f.submit '', class: 'btn home-add without-entry' %>
  <% end %>`            

  `<div class="col-xs-12 content-box" id="content-box">

    <p class="instructions count-instruction text-center">
      <%= @words.count %>
    </p>
    
 </div>` so what do i want to do in create.js.erb?

Comment: to replace the bottom **content-box** div alone?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember with AJAX is that you don't redirect the request (normally), you just generate some text to send back to the browser.  AJAX is basically just javascript to get some text from the browser and do something with it.  Often, you would want to replace a section of the page, ie replace an html tag and it's contents, with the text you get back, in which case you want the text to be some html.  The way to render a chunk of html in rails is to render a partial, so you do that, and you often also do some javascript to tell the browser what to do with the text, usually to replace an element that has a specific id with the text.

```
def create
  @new_note = current_user.notes.build(new_note_params)
  if @new_note.save 
    @notes_list = current_user.notes.count
    unless @new_note.user.any_entry
      @new_note.user.toggle!(:any_entry) if @notes_list >= 50
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.js #default behaviour is to run app/views/notes/create.js.erb file
  end
end
```

the respond_to block here allows you to treat html and js (eg ajax) requests differently.

The app/views/notes/create.js.erb could have something like

```
page.replace "foo", :partial => "app/views/notes/bar"
```

Comment: Please add `remote: true` to the form also else it will always send HTML request

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [respond_to block](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) in your controller action "create", and respective create.js.erb and put in your js that you want to get executed after the create action, and do post any error that you are getting on your browser console or rails server console, do that we can help you find where you are getting wrong

Comment: Hi @Suman ghosh, as mentioned earlier, i m new to rails. i did til **remote:true** that updates the DB. I m wondering how to show the updated content with **respond_to** as i never used it before. `<div class="col-xs-12 content-box" id="content-box"><%= @words.count %></div>` . I want to change the count everytime on ajax submit. so can u please help me with that respond_to section?

Comment: `format.html { redirect_to :back }
format.js` So what do i want to do in this section?

Comment: @PraveenKJ you are very close, you just need to write a create.js.erb file which updates the content of the <p > tag after a new record is created. So here you have to add an id to the <p> element whose content you want to update lets say `<p id="words-count" class="instructions count-instruction text-center">
      <%= @words.count %>
    </p>` and in create.js.erb => `$('#words-count').html("<%= @words_count %>");`(Assuming you have assigned words count in your action )