# Updating instance variables through AJAX call in Rails to display in form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. The user pastes a URL.
2. The input box that the user pastes in has an :onpaste that triggers urlPasted() function.
3. urlPasted() function submits the form that input box is in, which does an AJAX call to a custom function named lookup_profile.
4. In the controller, lookup_profile function does some web requests, and then updates some instance variables.
5. Once those variables are updated (takes ~5 seconds), the view has a function that waits 20 seconds and updates textboxes on the modal with the results of those instance variables.

Here's what I have thus far in the view:

```
  <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'lookup_profile'), id: "profileLookupForm", :method => 'post', :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true do  %>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <%= text_field_tag "paste_data", nil, onpaste: "profileURLPasted();", class: "form-control"%>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function profileURLPasted() {
        // Once the user pastes data, this is going to submit a POST request to the controller.
        setTimeout(function () { 
            document.getElementById("profileLookupForm").submit();
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function () { 
            prefillForm();
        }, 20000);
      };

    function prefillForm() {
    // Replace company details.
    $('#companyNameTextBox').val("<%= @company_name %>");
  };
  </script>
```

Here's what the controller looks like:

```
  def lookup_profile
    # bunch of code here
    @company_name = "Random"
  end
```

Now here's the problem I have. When the user pastes the data, it submits perfectly to the custom_action lookupProfile. However, after lookupProfile runs its code, rails doesn't know what to do afterwards. By that, I mean it gives me this error:

> Users#lookup_profile is missing a template for this request format and
> variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []

When in fact, I actually have a file at `views/users/lookup_profile.js.erb`. For some reason, it's trying to render the HTML version. I don't know why.

Secondly, I've tried putting this in the controller towards the end:

```
    respond_to do |format|  
        format.js { render 'users/lookup_profile'}
    end
```

but that results in this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I just want the custom function to run, update the instance variables, and let me update the current form with that data.

Here's another Stack Overflow reference of something similar I'm trying to do: [Rails submitting a form through ajax and updating the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312256/rails-submitting-a-form-through-ajax-and-updating-the-view) but this method doesn't work (getting the actioncontroller error)

### EDIT 1

OK, so I fixed the ActionController error by replacing my form_tag with:

```
<%= form_tag(lookup_profile_users_path(format: :js), method: :post, :authenticity_token => true, id: 'profileLookupForm', remote: true) do %>
```

But now it's actually rendering the actual JavaScript into the view, and I don't want that. I simply want to be able to access the instance variables that were updated in the lookup_profile action, not display the view.

### EDIT 2

So I think my problem comes down to this: Placing a button in the form and submitting from IT is different than my JavaScript code that submits the form. If I can figure out what's up with that, then I think I may be in good shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a few things there. First of all, instead of doing `document.getElementById("profileLookupForm").submit()` you should do an ajax request, I guess the `submit()` method ignores the `remote: true` directive from rails.

So, change the submission to:

```
form = getElementById("profileLookupForm");
$.post(form.action, {paste_data: this.value}, 'script')
// form.action is the url, `this` is the input field, 'script' tells rails it should render a js script
```

That way the request is done async and the response does not replace the current page.

Now, what I think you are mixing is that `@company_name` won't change with that ajax request. When you render the form and everything else, `@company_name` is replaced with the actual value IN THAT MOMENT and will not change after your post request since the reference is lost. So this line:

```
$('#companyNameTextBox').val("<%= @company_name %>");
```

will be

```
$('#companyNameTextBox').val("");
```

al the time.

What you want is to respond with a script that updates the field with the value that you set to `@company_name` (also, waiting arbitrarilly X seconds is a really bad practice).

So, instead of responding with:

```
format.js { render 'users/lookup_profile'}
```

create a view `lookup_profile.js` with the code that you want to execute

```
$('#companyNameTextBox').val("<%= @company_name %>");
```

here, `@company_name` will actually be the value obtained with those requests you told before, the script is generated at the moment and excecuted as a response of the request.

Comment: Thanks for the help here. For whatever reason, when the form is submitted using the post data you mentioned, the POST data does not contain "paste_data" or its value. It seems like this is the last thing. If I click submit on a button now following your other instructions, everything works (including replace the form text fields).