# No template found for Api::V1::BuildersController#update, rendering head :no_content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I have an edit builder profile page.
The desied output is when i click submit button it should show a div. That is it should show infomation saved successfully.

So i thought of writing an ajax code.

views/api/v1/builders/edit.html.erb is my view file and this is how i wrote the ajax code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#edit_submit_button").onClick(){
     var method_name = $('#url_method').val();
     $.ajax({
       url:relative_url_root() + "/" + method_name,
       success: function(){
         $(".save_alert_message").addClass('hide_div');
       }
     }).done();
   }
  });
</script>
```

and the div is

```
  <div class="save_alert_message hide_div">
    <%= "infomation saved successfully" %>
  </div>
```

and this are my Builder_controller methods.

```
  def edit
    @builder = Api::V1::Builder.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @builder = Api::V1::Builder.find(params[:id])
    if @builder.update_attributes(builder_params)
      session[:current_user] = @builder
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I am new to ajax. Someone please help me to solve this. How can i show the div if datas are successfully updated.

Comment: Are you trying to post form data to the `update` action or grab data from the `edit`action?

Comment: Like if my data s are successfully updated, i want to show the div without page refresh.

Comment: Instead of jquery I would use a `form_with`. By default, `local` is set to false which causes the form to submit an ajax update request which will update your record. If you want to respond with `js`, make a file named `views/api/v1/builders/update.js.erb` and put your Javascript in that file just like you would any other javascript file. There is no need to wrap your `js` in `<script>` tags if you implement it like this. You can remove the `respond_to` block if you implement this way.

Comment: Here is a link that does the same thing except you will want `form_with` and `local` instead of  `form_for` and `remote` since these have been deprecated.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312256/rails-submitting-a-form-through-ajax-and-updating-the-view

Comment: ok lemme try this , Thankyou